# Replacing element of a 2D object array

Tags: java, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, chess

I'm currently attempting to implement chess in Java and I think I'm getting hung up on something rather trivial but I can't debug the issue for the life of me.

Say I have a two-dimensional array of 'Piece' Subclasses (Pawn, Rook, Knight, etc. .), simple assignment with the "=" sign is not enough to replace one element with another, correct? As, it only creates a reference to the original.

For instance assume "field[][]" is an 8x8 array of instantiated chess pieces representing the board which I will iterate through to draw onto a JLayeredPane.

```
    field[dst_y][dst_x] = field[src_y][src_x]; 
    field[src_y][src_x] = null;
    field[dst_y][dst_x].setPosition(dst_y, dst_x); 
    // setPosition(int, int) just sets instance variables of the piece subclasses
```

Does this just create a reference to the element at field[src_y][src_x], place it in field[dst_y][dst_x] and immediately set them both to null? I am finding that I get a null pointer exception when attempting to update the board this way but all definite solutions involve me changing the data representation entirely, which would be unfortunate as I was happy with the logic I implemented already within the individual piece types to validate their moves from an (x,y) perspective.

Does this possibly have something to do with shallow-copying?

How could I ameliorate this? If the only answer is refactoring a significant amount of the code I am accepting of it, but I feel like I'm missing something embarrassingly simple.

**Board.java**

```
public class Board {

    private static final Board INSTANCE = new Board();
    private static Piece[][] field = new Piece[8][8];
    
    private Board() {}
    
    public static Board getInstance() {
        init();
        return INSTANCE;
        
    }
    
    public static Piece[][] getField(){
        return field;
    }
    
    public static void movePiece(int src_y, int src_x, int dst_y, int dst_x) {

        if(src_y != dst_y || src_x != dst_x) {
        field[dst_y][dst_x] = field[src_y][src_x]; 
        field[src_y][src_x] = null;
        field[dst_y][dst_x].setPosition(dst_y, dst_x);
        }
    }
    
    public static void init() {
        
        field[0][0] = new Rook(0, 0, true);
        field[0][1] = new Knight(0, 1, true);
        field[0][2] = new Bishop(0, 2, true);
        field[0][3] = new Queen(0, 3, true);
        field[0][4] = new King(0, 4, true);
        field[0][5] = new Bishop(0, 5, true);
        field[0][6] = new Knight(0, 6, true);
        field[0][7] = new Rook(0, 7, true);
        
        
        field[1][0] = new Pawn(1, 0, true);
        field[1][1] = new Pawn(1, 1, true);
        field[1][2] = new Pawn(1, 2, true);
        field[1][3] = new Pawn(1, 3, true);
        field[1][4] = new Pawn(1, 4, true);
        field[1][5] = new Pawn(1, 5, true);
        field[1][6] = new Pawn(1, 6, true);
        field[1][7] = new Pawn(1, 7, true);
        
        for(int i = 2; i < 6; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                field[i][j] = null;
            }
        }
        
        field[7][0] = new Rook(7, 0, false);
        field[7][1] = new Knight(7, 1, false);
        field[7][2] = new Bishop(7, 2, false);
        field[7][3] = new Queen(7, 3, false);
        field[7][4] = new King(7, 4, false);
        field[7][5] = new Bishop(7, 5, false);
        field[7][6] = new Knight(7, 6, false);
        field[7][7] = new Rook(7, 7, false);
        
        field[6][0] = new Pawn(6, 0, false);
        field[6][1] = new Pawn(6, 1, false);
        field[6][2] = new Pawn(6, 2, false);
        field[6][3] = new Pawn(6, 3, false);
        field[6][4] = new Pawn(6, 4, false);
        field[6][5] = new Pawn(6, 5, false);
        field[6][6] = new Pawn(6, 6, false);
        field[6][7] = new Pawn(6, 7, false);
        
    }
}
```

**Game.java** (Mostly taken from a blog post to test out the logical issues quickly)

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
 
public class Game extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
  JLayeredPane layeredPane;
  JPanel chessBoard;
  JLabel chessPiece;
  int xAdjustment;
  int yAdjustment;
  final static Color DARK = new Color(209, 139, 71);
  final static Color LIGHT = new Color(255, 206, 158);
  
  int src_x = 0;
  int src_y = 0;
  int dst_x = 0;
  int dst_y = 0;
  
  Board b = Board.getInstance();
  Piece[][] field = b.getField();
 
  public Game(){
  Dimension boardSize = new Dimension(600, 600);
 
  //  Use a Layered Pane for this this application
 layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
  getContentPane().add(layeredPane);
  layeredPane.setPreferredSize(boardSize);
  layeredPane.addMouseListener(this);
  layeredPane.addMouseMotionListener(this);
 
  //Add a chess board to the Layered Pane 
 
  chessBoard = new JPanel();
  layeredPane.add(chessBoard, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
  chessBoard.setLayout( new GridLayout(8, 8) );
  chessBoard.setPreferredSize( boardSize );
  chessBoard.setBounds(0, 0, boardSize.width, boardSize.height);
 
  for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
  JPanel square = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
  chessBoard.add( square );
 
  int row = (i / 8) % 2;
  if (row == 0)
  square.setBackground( i % 2 == 0 ? LIGHT : DARK);
  else
  square.setBackground( i % 2 == 0 ? DARK : LIGHT);
  }
  
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
          if(field[i][j] != null) {
          JLabel pic = new JLabel(field[i][j].getIcon());
          JPanel panel = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(((8 * i) + j));
          panel.add(pic);
          }
      }
  }
  
  }
 
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
  chessPiece = null;
  Component c =  chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
 
  if (c instanceof JPanel) 
  return;
 
  Point parentLocation = c.getParent().getLocation();
  xAdjustment = parentLocation.x - e.getX();
  yAdjustment = parentLocation.y - e.getY();
  
  src_x = e.getX() / 75;
  src_y = e.getY() / 75;
  
  System.out.println("==========\nSource X: " + src_x + "\nSource Y: " + src_y + "\n==========");
  
  chessPiece = (JLabel)c;
  chessPiece.setLocation(e.getX() + xAdjustment, e.getY() + yAdjustment);
  chessPiece.setSize(chessPiece.getWidth(), chessPiece.getHeight());
  layeredPane.add(chessPiece, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
  }
 
  //Move the chess piece around
  
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
  if (chessPiece == null) return;
 chessPiece.setLocation(me.getX() + xAdjustment, me.getY() + yAdjustment);
 }
 
  //Drop the chess piece back onto the chess board
 
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
  if(chessPiece == null) return;
  
  dst_x = e.getX() / 75;
  dst_y = e.getY() / 75;
  
  // This is where the null pointer exception occurs
  chessPiece.setVisible(false);
  Component c =  chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
  System.out.println("Destination X: " + dst_x + "\nDestination Y: " + dst_y);
  
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
          if(field[i][j] != null) {
          System.out.print(field[i][j].toString());
          System.out.print(field[i][j].isWhite() ? "true" : "false");
          System.out.println();
          
          
          }
          else {
              System.out.println("(" + j + ", " + i + ") = NULL");
          }
      }
  }
  
  Board.movePiece(src_y, src_x, dst_y, dst_x);
  field = Board.getField();
    
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
          if(field[i][j] != null) {
          JLabel pic = new JLabel(field[i][j].getIcon());
          JPanel panel = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(((8 * i) + j));
          panel.add(pic);
          }
      }
  }
  
  
 
  if (c instanceof JLabel){
  Container parent = c.getParent();
  parent.remove(0);
  parent.add( chessPiece );
  }
  else {
  Container parent = (Container)c;
  parent.add( chessPiece );
  }
 
  chessPiece.setVisible(true);
  }
  
 
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
  
  }
  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
 }
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
  
  }
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
  
  }
 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  JFrame frame = new Game();
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
  frame.pack();
  frame.setResizable(true);
  frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
  frame.setVisible(true);
  
 }
}
```

**Piece.java**

```
import java.lang.Math;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.*;
public abstract class Piece implements MoveStrategy{

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private boolean white;
    
    public abstract ImageIcon getIcon();
    
    public Piece(int pos_y, int pos_x, boolean white) {
        setPosition(pos_y, pos_x);
        setColor(white);
    }
    
    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
    
    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }
    
    public void setPosition(int dst_y, int dst_x) {
        this.x = dst_x;
        this.y = dst_y;
    }
    
    public boolean isWhite() {
        return this.white;
    }
    
    private void setColor(boolean white) {
        this.white = white;
    }
    
    
}
```

**Pawn.java**

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Pawn extends Piece {

    public Pawn(int pos_y, int pos_x, boolean white) {
        super(pos_y, pos_x, white);
    }
    
    public ImageIcon getIcon() {
        ImageIcon icon = (this.isWhite() == true) ? new ImageIcon("WhitePawn.png") : new ImageIcon("BlackPawn.png");
        return icon;
    }

    public boolean validateMove(int dst_x, int dst_y, Piece[][] field) {
        
        int x = this.getX();
        int y = this.getY();
        boolean iw = this.isWhite();
        
        // If either dst_x/y param is out of array bounds return false
        if(dst_x > 7 || dst_y > 7 || dst_x < 0 || dst_y < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        
        // Logic if the piece is white
        if(iw) {
            // Can move two
            if(y == 1) {
                // If not moving horizontally, not moving more than 2 vertically, moving at least one space, and moving
                // into an open square, return true.
                if(x == dst_x && dst_y - y <= 2 && dst_y - y > 0 && field[dst_x][dst_y] == null)  return true;
                // If moving one diagonally into a spot occupied by the other team's piece, return true.
                if(Math.abs(x - dst_x) == 1 && dst_y == y + 1 && field[dst_x][dst_y] != null && field[dst_x][dst_y].isWhite() == false) return true;
                
            }
            else {
                if(dst_x == x + 1 && dst_y == y + 1 && field[dst_x][dst_y] != null && field[dst_x][dst_y].isWhite() == false) return true;
                if(Math.abs(x - dst_x) == 1 && dst_y == y + 1 && field[dst_x][dst_y] != null && field[dst_x][dst_y].isWhite() == false) return true;

            }
        }
        // Logic if the piece is black
        else {
            // Calculations same as above but for black pieces
            if(y == 6) {
                if(x == dst_x && y - dst_y <= 2 && y - dst_y > 0 && field[dst_x][dst_y] == null)  return true;
                if(Math.abs(dst_x - x) == 1 && dst_y - y == 1 && field[dst_x][dst_y] != null && field[dst_x][dst_y].isWhite() == true) return true;

            }
            else {
                if(x == dst_x && y - dst_y == 1 && field[dst_x][dst_y] == null)  return true;
                if(Math.abs(dst_x - x) == 1 && dst_y - y == 1 && field[dst_x][dst_y] != null && field[dst_x][dst_y].isWhite() == true) return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        String s = "Type: Pawn" + " Position (" + this.getX() + ", " + this.getY() + ")";
        return s;
    }

}
```

**Stack trace when dragging one piece over another, or when moving a piece into an empty space sometimes**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Board.movePiece(Board.java:24)
at Game.mouseReleased(Game.java:106)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Could you post a minimum runnable sample?

Comment: Sure, I will do that right now, It's a significant amount of code, though, as it includes an abstract class and its subclasses (the types of pieces). I really appreciate it.

Comment: No.  `field[dst_y][dst_x] = field[src_y][src_x];` simply sets `field[dst_y][dst_x]` so that it now references the same thing that `field[src_y][src_x]` references.  Then `field[src_y][src_x]=null;` simply sets `field[src_y][src_x]` to `null` and `field[dst_y][dst_x]` continues to reference whatever it was referencing before (which is whatever `field[src_y][src_y]` was previously referencing).  `field[dst_y][dst_x]=field[src_y][src_x]` **did not** somehow make `field[dst_y][dst_x]` a _synoym_ for `field{src_y][src_x]`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Okay, great! Thank you for the response and for clearing that up. My apologies for the ignorance of my question. So the issue must exist somewhere else where I'm attempting to access a null value?  The stack trace is very helpful, as well as attempting to debug where the error occurs but haven't been able to find any sort of root cause yet.

Comment: You've asked for help. Please don't handicap us. Please paste the full stack trace into the question.

Comment: @NomadMaker I'm sorry for that! I thought I had, it's now updated with the stack trace and some context around what caused it. This occurs when the movePiece() method is called on an element of the Piece array. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't see where your problem is, but I see a large problem with your logic. The position of a piece is in multiple places. This can lead to errors. To minimize this, only allow the positions to be changed by a single method which changes all this information at once so that everything stays synchronized.

Comment: @NomadMaker I believe see what you mean. I will remove the piece's instance variables referring to their own location, and just pass their index as a parameter directly from the 2d array into the verifyMove() method. Not doing so from the beginning was quite the oversight. Thank you.

Comment: arghh... there is no method `Board.movePiece` in the code shown, only in the stack trace.

Comment: @NikolaiDmitriev I'm sorry for the confusion and having so much the parse through to make sense of my issue here. I call Board.movePiece() in the mouseReleased() method of Game.java, though only once. And it's definition should be included in what I pasted from Board.java, it's also what I'm referencing in the first small code snippet about the 2d array assignment. I appreciate your help.

Comment: ok, ok ... don't worry ;) It's the primordial frustration of the hunter. The stack trace leads you to the pray and at the indicated location is ... nothing

Comment: @NikolaiDmitriev Hahah, Yes. I made this way too difficult on myself by keeping the location of the Pieces in their own separate instance variables. I will refactor the code to include the piece's location as a parameter to the method interface method verifyMove() which checks if a given move is valid. Looking at the instantiation of the array now shows me how redundant and error-prone this was. I believe that may solve my issues, or at least bring me closer... I hope lol